# django - url with no argument to take a default value

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Suppose, this is an `url` which takes an argument (here, `book_id`) and pass the value to the `views`:

```
url(r'^/(?P<book_id>\w+)/$', 'pro.views.book', name='book'),
```

Is it possible for a url which takes an argument, but, if no argument is given, take a default value. If possible may be in the `views` too. I am sorry if this is a lame question, but I really need to know. Any help or suggestion will be grateful. Thank you

Comment: from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#notes-on-capturing-text-in-urls)

Comment: Should have looked into the docs. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make the capturing pattern optional, and remember to deal with a trailing slash appropriately. I'd find a noncapturing group around the capturing group the safest way to do that:

```
url(r'^(?:(?P<book_id>\w+)/)?$', 'pro.views.book', name='book'),
```

Then in the views, declare a default for the argument:

```
def book(request, book_id='default'):
```

If you find that URL pattern ugly, you can bind two regexps to the same view function:

```
url(r'^(?P<book_id>\w+)/$', 'pro.views.book', name='book'),
url(r'^$', 'pro.views.book', name='default_book'),
```

Following Alasdair's reminder, I have removed the leading slash. I thought that looked odd.

Comment: +1 including both approaches, personally I much prefer two regexps

Comment: Yeah, I tend to use that approach myself - though that's partly just because I'm usually too lazy to refresh my memory on noncapturing group syntax.

Comment: Woah! I would have never thought of that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

this very old topic but maybe someone want known hot to do this today.

**First method** is add in view default val:
def someView(request, val1=0, val2=0):

and create two url paths to this view:
path('myurl/',view.someView, name='someview'),
path('myurl/int:val1/int:val2/',view.someView, name='someview),

Another methos is use in template link like this: href="{% url 'someView'  %}?val1=1200"

and check in view is val1 exists
if  request.GET.get('val1'):
doSomething